# Knowing whether a string can be extended while matching a regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Suppose I have a regex `r` and a string `s` known to match `r`.

Is there a way in JavaScript to check if this is true:

> There is a character `c` that can be appended to `s` such that `s + c` still matches `r`

I don't see a direct way (for example using RegExp methods) for this, so maybe someone knows a trick to do this?

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: It is definitely true under certain circumstances. For instance, I claim that if `r` ends with something that is neither `$` nor `)`, it is true. However, `r` could end with those characters and the claim could still be true. If `r` has more than two characters and ends with [not `)`] followed by `*$`, then I think it's true

Comment: @ChrisLear your first claim is not valid for `^(?=.$).+` and similar constructs

Comment: It doesn't seem I can edit my question, so I'll give an example here: for the regex ^\d\.\d\d? the string 1.1 matches and you can add a character (any digit). 1.12 also matches the regex but you can't add any character.

Comment: @SebastianProske thanks - this is interesting.

Comment: A similar counter-example to my second claim: `^(?=.$).*$`

Comment: As I see it, it's a **major** task, since you basically have to parse the whole regex. If a regex looks like `^(?:a.*|\d{3}|@[^@]*)$`, you'd have to consider all three alternations to decide if a certain character can be added. So my answer is - it *can't* be done.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. It depends on what your regex is. if you have for example a regex `/^\w+$/` then adding characters to that string will still match. But not if the regex is already limited to the current string, for example `/^\w{3}$/` will match 'abc' but not 'abcd'.  The question could benefit from some examples and expectations.

Comment: can't you just brute force it? I mean looping through all valid characters `c` and try if `s+c` matches with `r`.

Comment: Well, that's what I was trying to avoid,but I don't think I will be able to. Hopefully, in many case, those valid characters are limited, so I can reduce the brute force space. But I have to compute this space. Not hard but boring.